# Java jsoup checking button

Tags: java, html, web, jsoup

I am trying to check whether a page contains next page to sroll. The idea is basic: get the current link, remove the index at the end and then put new index, try to connect to the new link, if it throws IOException that means it does not have next button so that can be scrolled. Here is my code, and the problem it returns false even to the links that Jsoup can connect:

```
public boolean checkNextButton(String linkToCheck) throws IOException {

        boolean containsNextButton = true;
        try {
            //Here I am trying to connect to a link which is actually available but it still returns false
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(turnToNextPage(linkToCheck)).get();
            specific.setPageChangeRate(specific.getPageChangeRate() - 1);
            //Set back the counter to the previous one
        } catch (IOException e) {

            containsNextButton = false;
        }
        System.out.println("The page contains next button: " + containsNextButton);
        return containsNextButton;
    }
```

Comment: It is hard to tell what exactly went wrong without more details. Are you able to access resource from `linkToCheck` via browser? Did you need to log-in on that site first (maybe try accessing it via incognito mode to see if it is available for anyone without creating an account). Other problem could be that some servers allow only specific browsers and they try to recognize them by using user-agent header browsers send, or if server is creating temporary session you may need to pass cookies from previous connection.

Comment: yes I can access through the browser, but let me check for the other issues that you mentioned :)

Comment: @Pshemo thank you so much it was because of the user-agent as you mentioned, now it returns true

Answer (score 0):

Solution provided by [Pshemo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1393766/pshemo):

> It is hard to tell what exactly went wrong without more details.
>
> Are you able to access resource from `linkToCheck` via browser? Did you need to log-in on that site first (maybe try accessing it via incognito mode to see if it is available for anyone without creating an account).
>
> Other problem could be that some servers allow only specific browsers and they try to recognize them by using user-agent header browsers send, or if server is creating temporary session you may need to pass cookies from previous connection.